# What happens to the "application.properties" file when a spring boot application is built

Tags: spring-boot, properties-file

I am trying to understand what Spring Boot does with the "application.properties" file. I know it configures the application, but when I look inside the final JAR file gradle creates (its spring boot+gradle), I cannot find the application.properties file. 
My applications works fine. But I'm curious what happens to the application.properties when the application is built and how my configurations finds its way in to the application. Can someone shed light on this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your application.properties file is in the folder src/main/resources, then it should be packaged in the root of the JAR. If it's in another location, then it won't be packaged and you have to make sure, that the application will have the right configuration when it's executed.

Comment: But what if it is not in that location? I have mine at the root of the project folder (such as "<project_name>/application.properties"). This file has the following configurations multipart.maxFileSize=500Mb|multipart.maxRequestSize=500Mb|server.port=8008 (separated by new lines). These settings do work. But the property file is no where to be found in the JAR.

Comment: As i said, then it is not packaged and it is up to you how you get that file into your environment. If you want to have it in the JAR, move it to src/main/resources.

Comment: Yes I get that point. But how those settings in my application.properties file find their way in to the JAR? Does spring boot creates some configuration beans using them? Or some other magic happens?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "find their way in to the JAR"? Do you mean what happens during runtime?

Comment: For example, when I specify server.port=8008, where does it get stored in the JAR? Because I don't see any properties file inside the JAR. I only see bunch of .class files in the JAR (except for MANIFEST.MF in META-INF But when I execute the JAR, the embedded tomcat starts listening at 8008 . So how is it happening?

Comment: Where do you specify that property?

Comment: In an application.properties file sitting right outside of the project folder. That file is a sibling of src, build directories and build.gradle, gradle.properties and settings.gradle files.

Comment: In that case Spring Boot reads the property file, because it's in one of locations where Spring Boot looks for them, and applies them at runtime. It doesn't store them in the JAR or anywhere else.